# ninja build does not pick flags while running build

Tags: cmake, compilation, llvm, ninja

I am trying to build llvm code (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git) using cmake with Ninja generator.
So basically as a first step i am configuring cmake with Ninja generator :-

cmake configure command:-

`cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=d:\buildbot-worker\worker\llvm-dev-nvptx-win/install -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=llvm -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=ON -DLLVM_LIT_ARGS=-vv -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86;NVPTX -DLLVM_DEFAULT_TARGET_TRIPLE=nvptx-nvidia-cuda -DLLVM_OPTIMIZED_TABLEGEN=ON -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=/manifest:no -DCMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS=/manifest:no -DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS=/manifest:no -Wno-dev d:\buildbot-worker\worker\llvm-dev-nvptx-win/llvm`

Note:- i am passing `/manifest:no` to not invoke mt.exe (manifest related) during linking stage.

even in `CmakeCache.txt` file also i found following variables set :-

```
//Flags used by the linker during all build types.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=/manifest:no
/Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// all build types.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=/manifest:no
//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during all build types.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=/manifest:no
```

Above configure command generates `build.ninja` that defines all rules, Here i am listing one such rule:-

```
build bin\llvm-tblgen.exe: CXX_EXECUTABLE_LINKER__llvm-tblgen_RelWithDebInfo utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\obj.LLVMTableGenCommon.dir\Attributes.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\obj.LLVMTableGenCommon.dir\CodeGenIntrinsics.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\obj.LLVMTableGenCommon.dir\DirectiveEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\obj.LLVMTableGenCommon.dir\IntrinsicEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\obj.LLVMTableGenCommon.dir\RISCVTargetDefEmitter.cpp.obj ....
......
  FLAGS = /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS   /Zc:inline /Zc:preprocessor /Zc:__cplusplus /Oi /bigobj /permissive- /W4 -wd4141 -wd4146 -wd4244 -wd4267 -wd4291 -wd4351 -wd4456 -wd4457 -wd4458 -wd4459 -wd4503 -wd4624 -wd4722 -wd4100 -wd4127 -wd4512 -wd4505 -wd4610 -wd4510 -wd4702 -wd4245 -wd4706 -wd4310 -wd4701 -wd4703 -wd4389 -wd4611 -wd4805 -wd4204 -wd4577 -wd4091 -wd4592 -wd4319 -wd4709 -wd5105 -wd4324 -w14062 -we4238 /Gw /Zi /O2 /Ob1  -MD
  LINK_FLAGS = /manifest:no /STACK:10000000 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console
  LINK_LIBRARIES = lib\LLVMCodeGenTypes.lib  lib\LLVMSupport.lib  lib\LLVMTableGen.lib  lib\LLVMTableGenGlobalISel.lib  lib\LLVMCodeGenTypes.lib  lib\LLVMTableGen.lib  lib\LLVMSupport.lib  psapi.lib  shell32.lib  ole32.lib  uuid.lib  advapi32.lib  delayimp.lib  -delayload:shell32.dll  -delayload:ole32.dll  lib\LLVMDemangle.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib
  OBJECT_DIR = utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir
  POST_BUILD = cd .
  PRE_LINK = cd .
  TARGET_COMPILE_PDB = utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\
  TARGET_FILE = bin\llvm-tblgen.exe
  TARGET_IMPLIB = lib\llvm-tblgen.lib
  TARGET_PDB = bin\llvm-tblgen.pdb
```

So the rule with target file `bin\llvm-tblgen.exe` has `LINK_FLAGS` with `/manifest:no`.

During build while linking stage, My build fails with following issue:-

```
FAILED: bin/llvm-tblgen.exe 
    cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100226~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100226~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~3\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1433~1.316\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\obj.LLVMTableGenCommon.dir\Attributes.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\obj.LLVMTableGenCommon.dir\CodeGenIntrinsics.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\obj.LLVMTableGenCommon.dir\DirectiveEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\obj.LLVMTableGenCommon.dir\IntrinsicEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\obj.LLVMTableGenCommon.dir\RISCVTargetDefEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\obj.LLVMTableGenCommon.dir\SDNodeProperties.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\obj.LLVMTableGenCommon.dir\VTEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\AsmMatcherEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\AsmWriterEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\AsmWriterInst.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\CTagsEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\CallingConvEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\CodeEmitterGen.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\CodeGenDAGPatterns.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\CodeGenHwModes.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\CodeGenInstAlias.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\CodeGenInstruction.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\CodeGenMapTable.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\CodeGenRegisters.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\CodeGenSchedule.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\CodeGenTarget.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\DAGISelEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\DAGISelMatcherEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\DAGISelMatcherGen.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\DAGISelMatcherOpt.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\DAGISelMatcher.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\DecoderEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\DFAEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\DFAPacketizerEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\DisassemblerEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\DXILEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\ExegesisEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\FastISelEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\GICombinerEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\GlobalISelCombinerMatchTableEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\GlobalISelEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\GlobalISelMatchTable.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\GlobalISelMatchTableExecutorEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\InfoByHwMode.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\InstrInfoEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\InstrDocsEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\OptEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\OptParserEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\OptRSTEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\PredicateExpander.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\PseudoLoweringEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\CompressInstEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\RegisterBankEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\RegisterInfoEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\SearchableTableEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\SubtargetEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir
r\VarLenCodeEmitterGen.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\X86DisassemblerTables.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\X86EVEX2VEXTablesEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\X86FoldTablesEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\X86MnemonicTables.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\X86ModRMFilters.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\X86RecognizableInstr.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\WebAssemblyDisassemblerEmitter.cpp.obj utils\TableGen\CMakeFiles\llvm-tblgen.dir\__\__\resources\windows_version_resource.rc.res  /out:bin\llvm-tblgen.exe /implib:lib\llvm-tblgen.lib /pdb:bin\llvm-tblgen.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /STACK:10000000 /INCREMENTAL:NO /subsystem:console  lib\LLVMCodeGenTypes.lib  lib\LLVMSupport.lib  lib\LLVMTableGen.lib  lib\LLVMTableGenGlobalISel.lib  lib\LLVMCodeGenTypes.lib  lib\LLVMTableGen.lib  lib\LLVMSupport.lib  psapi.lib  shell32.lib  ole32.lib  uuid.lib  advapi32.lib  delayimp.lib  -delayload:shell32.dll  -delayload:ole32.dll  lib\LLVMDemangle.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."



MT: command "C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100226~1.0\x64\mt.exe /nologo /manifest bin\llvm-tblgen.exe.manifest /outputresource:bin\llvm-tblgen.exe;#1" failed (exit code 0x1f) with the following output:
mt.exe : general error c101008d: Failed to write the updated manifest to the resource of file "bin\llvm-tblgen.exe". The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

when it fails it also shows the command it rans (see the `cmd.exe /C ...` above) where i dont see `/manifest:no` passed to the linker. Why is it happening ? though `build.ninja` file has the rule with `/manifest:no` during build stage it is not reflecting in command causes build failure.

I don't find anywhere that overriding flags happening internal to build system files. How can i fix this issue? I don't understand what is missing here.

Comment: can you grep for `llvm-tblgen.exe.manifest` in the build directory to see if any build rules mention it?

Comment: the only pace I see ".manifest" related to executables is in `Source/cmMakefileExecutableTargetGenerator.cxx` to specify such files to be cleaned when needed.

Comment: @starball, I am trying to not invoke mt.exe itself. Some reason it's not being passed to command .it is the only way to fix the issue in my case.. FYI I am following this :- https://github.com/KDAB/GammaRay/issues/458